# MSAccess VBA Control.Parent Irregularities

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I discovered `Control.Parent` may refer to either a `Form` OR it might also be a `Page` if it's in a `TabControl`. In the past, I've simply snagged the parent, and it was a form, even for controls on tabs. What's confounding me more, is `subform` controls appear to have the `Form` as `.Parent`, but no other controls do (note, this may not always be true as indicated by @FunThomas); but it is the case in my version of Access).

[MSAccess's Control.Parent Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.control.parent) while being fairly terse, just says "Returns the parent object for the specified object."  Some research has [stated the control parent is the form](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/refer-to-control-within-a-tab-control-in-vba.27700/), even for controls on tabs, so I'm more confused. Even [Microsoft's page on referring to controls says either are valid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/controls/refer-to-tab-control-objects-in-vba), which makes me wonder if this ever worked in the past, or I'm just imagining it.

Given a `Form` named *TopForm*, and a `TabControl` named *TabCtl1*, a `Page` named *TabPage1*, and various controls (`SubForm`, `TextBox`, etc.) are on a Tab Page in a form, the following appears to be the case.

[This question is related to an answer I gave over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71176443/16107370), and is asked to flesh out an edge case I discovered while implementing the solution for my use.

Note: ALL controls in this case are on a "Page" (Subform is on another tab page because reasons):[image]

| Control Type | `Control.Parent` Returns | Parent Type | Expected Parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TabCtl1 | TopForm | Form | TopForm |
| TabPage1 | TabCtl1 | TabControl | TabCtl1 |
| TabPage2 | TabCtl1 | TabControl | TabCtl1 |
| SubFormCtl | TopForm | Form | TabPage2 |
| ListBoxCtl | TabPage1 | Tab Page | Tab Page 1 |
| TextBoxCtl | TabPage1 | Tab Page | Tab Page 1 |

And now, the question: What am I doing wrong? Do I need to loop through all the parents until I get the Control's parent form?

Comment: I think its in `ctl.properties.parent.form`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why don't you call the form by name, e.g. `Forms.TopForm...`?

Comment: I've built a control log, and I need the specific ID of a control to 1: undo that action, 2: log the user's changes (for UI testing, which will be turned off later), 3: audit tracing for changes. In order to do that, and make it extensible, I need to get a control's parent form.  

I'm mostly confused why "Subform Controls" parent is the form (even if it's on the tab), and any other controls (when they're on a tab) is the page, and not the form. The inconsistency is what's getting me.'

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: I think you're on to something; initial testing appears to always have this be the Parent form regardless of the control type. Still odd that there's inconsistency. I'll do some testing and update.

Comment: Ok, that doesn't work: `ctl.properties.parent.form` of a top form is another form (itself). So I need to figure out if it's got a parent form or not

Comment: Well, I see little reason to use some control.Parent, when in code you want the parent form of the current form. In this case, just ALWAYS use me.Parent to get the parent form, and thus the problem has little to do with attempting to use some control to get the parent. A parent of a control vs the parent form that houses the current sub form are two very different concepts. So, if you in code want the parent form, then always use me.parent. In a tab control, you are 100% free to use any other control in the current form, and no nesting or mycontrol.parent is required anyway.

Comment: Quite so @AlbertD.Kallal: I really only want the parent form of specific controls. What is confusing the issue is that while I traverse up the "stack" of parents, I also grab the name of the control/parent. This way, I can have a very specific "ID string" per-se of what control changed. The issue is not getting the top form, it's ensuring the control 'address' is consistently built, and therefore consistently able to be parsed by the audit tools and undo routines, especially for forms with sub-sub forms where the sub forms may be repeated.

Comment: at any point in code, me.parent will always be the parent form. And I would traverse by sub form controls to get to a specific control at a given level. You can't get to a control two sub forms deep unless you have the sub forms reference anyway. So, it not clear how you could have got some control reference in the first place without having the sub form reference first? Since you have the forms reference first to then get  control reference, I don't actually see the need to use some control.parent - only exception here would be when using a sub-form control, .parent of sub form can be used.

Comment: Good question: here's how I do it: (note, I need to add in some updates I've made, but here's the gist): https://stackoverflow.com/a/71176443/16107370

Comment: Also: me.parent is not the parent form when "me" is the control; the parent of the control is wherever it lives. When you have a control on a subform (or anywhere, really) , parsing the control's address will have me.parent (or ctl.parent) = parent object, except with subform controls (or...as best I can tell on my particular flavor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing and head scratching, I found the solution to be rather more simple than expected. I used @Nathan_Sav's and @FunThomas's and ended up melding them to ensure I could do what I needed.

I am after the parent form as suggested by @AlbertD.Kallal (so I could select the parent `Form` and the child `Control` and revert the action if needed, or simply log the change). I wanted the parent form because it's easiest and most consistent to simply use `FrmInUse.ControlToActOn.WhateverINeedToDo` instead of going down the tree. This method is used in the other answer I posted recently: ["Access VBA - How to get the properties of a parent subform, or, get the user-given name for a subform (not the object reference name)"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71176443/16107370). This question was trying to figure out why the `.Parent` was not consistently returned.

It would be possible, I suppose, to activate all the controls down to the one I wanted (it would ensure tabs are open to the desired location), however, users indicated that did not do what they expected AND that also fires events (even though [Microsoft's TabControl.Change Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.tabcontrol.change) says VBA won't trigger the event, I found in practice that is patently not true in my version of Access).

To get the `Parent` of a `Control` in a manner consistently parsed by a loop (`Form.SfrmControl.Sfrm.CtrlIWant` or `Form.CtrlIWant`) and given that the `Control` or `Form` has a parent object (checked elsewhere), this gets what I was looking for.

```
If TypeOf ControlTarget Is Form Then
    Set ParentForm = ControlTarget.Parent
Else
    Set ParentForm = ControlTarget.Properties.Parent.Form
End If
```

The code is then used like this: (pseudo code while we polish it up and test for edge cases, I plan on posting the fully built class and components later).

```
Public Sub GetAddress(ByRef FormOrControlTarget As Object) As String

    Dim ParentForm As Access.Form

    If TypeOf FormOrControlTarget Is Form Then
        Set ParentForm = FormOrControlTarget.Parent
    Else
        Set ParentForm = FormOrControlTarget.Properties.Parent.Form
    End If

    If ParentForm Is Nothing Then
        GetAddress = FormOrControlTarget.Name & FormOrControlTarget.Hwnd
    ElseIf FormOrControlTarget Is Form Then 
        ' Note: the below line won't work as-is, you'll need to search the parent form 
        '      for it; I'll update this and the relevant code when it's ready to go.
        GetAddress = ParentForm.Name & ParentForm.SfrmControl.Name & FormOrControlTarget.Name & FormOrControlTarget.Hwnd
    Else 
        GetAddress = ParentForm.Name & ParentForm.Hwnd & FormOrControlTarget.Name
    End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Controls "live" inside other controls. You can get the control they live in via the property `Parent`.
If a control has one or several controls "inside", you can get a list via the property `Controls`, but note that not all control types can have children, eg a label can't have child controls and has no `Controls`-property.

This parent-child relationship can be cascading. You can have a Tab Control with pages, and a page can contain an group of option button. You would have something like

```
Form
  TabControl
     Page 1
        Frame 2
          Label 3
          Check 4
```

Are you sure that your subform is on a Page control? If yes, it should have the Page control as parent, not the Main form - at least that is the case in an example I did to test my code.

Labels that are linked to a control, eg the label next to an input field have that control as parent.  As a rule of thumb: If you move a control and other controls are moved with it, then those controls are childs and the control you are moving is the parent.

The following function will return the top-most parent, that should be the form.

```
Function getForm(ctrl As Variant) As Variant
    Dim Parent As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    Set parent = ctrl.parent
    On Error GoTo 0

    If IsEmpty(parent) Then
        Set getForm = ctrl
    Else
        Set getForm = getForm(parent)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I'm certain it's on the page control (just built another test case and put a subform in it); the parent of a subform control (at least in Access 2016/365) appears to always be the form; all other controls's parents are indeed the page (expected, or apparently is now).

Comment: as noted, if you have a sub form, and want the parent, then always use me.Parent. When using a tab control, and each tab is not a sub form? Then any code in any tab is free to directly refernce any other control in the other tabs, and once again I see no need for mycontrol.parent to be used in code? So, if you need/want the parent form that holds the sub form your code in running in, then always use me.parent. I actually don't see much of any case for using mycontrol.parent when you want the parent form. As noted, in a tab control, any and all code can direct reference any other control.

Comment: Strange. I am on Office 365 (Version 2201). My Subform shows the parent I expect. If it is placed on a Page, I get that Page control as parent.

Comment: I made a whole new form, when I iterate up through the ranks, the subform control still shows `sfrmctl.Parent` as the parent form, not the tab / page it's on. All the rest act as expected.